# How do I find files with a name greater than 50 characters in Windows?

Tags: cmd.exe

I have a folder with 20000 files, need to list only files with names greater than 50 characters and save in txt.
Files will be imported into an application, it usually recognizes files that are up to 50 characters long.

Comment: There are many ways to do this. Knowing what you want to do woth those files would help pick the best method.

Comment: Files will be imported into an application, it usually recognizes files that are up to 50 characters long.

Comment: Q&(very)D: `dir/b | findstr ...................................................` where there are 51 dots in the argument to `findstr`

Comment: I have already tried this code, it listed files smaller than 50 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Normally here on Superuser we expect a statement of the problem, then the attemped solution, (hopefully showing the code), and finally a specific question about how to make it work. 
 We are not a software development service.

Having said that, let me point you to the easiest way:

Write a simple Python script using the os library.
It can open the directory and step through all the files one by one.
Using the len() function you could easily have it ignore any less than 50.

Output would be printed to the console so you can redirect it as you please.

The program would only be about 10 lines long.

Comment: Sorry, I already edited the topic. I was able to create in powershell `Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.Name.Length -gt 50} | Select Directory,Name,@{Name="NameLength";Expression={$_.Name.lengt‌​h}}` Now I would like to know if it is possible to do the same using CMD

Answer (score 0):

- List all files by dir command:

  dir C: /b /s /A-D /o:gn > ListRaw.TxT
- Open the text file. Copy paste the content into a sort-text-by-length tool like [this one](http://www.miniwebtool.com/sort-text-by-length/)
- Sort it.
- Paste the result in another text file
- Look where the characters start exceed 50 and delete the not need half
- Save the final file.